# Why is zmq_recv() with a ZMQ_DONTWAIT returning an errno == 0 instead of EAGAIN?

Tags: windows, zeromq, nonblocking

I'm writing a small test app using `ZeroMQ`.

One test scenario I have is when there is no server running to connect to.

So, I'm passing `ZMQ_DONTWAIT` to `zmq_recv()` in that scenario expecting an error of `EAGAIN` but instead getting `errno` value of 0.

Sample client code below:

```
int rc;

void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
void *requester = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_REQ);
int nLingerOption = 0;
rc = zmq_setsockopt(requester, ZMQ_LINGER, &nLingerOption, sizeof(nLingerOption));
rc = zmq_connect(requester, "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");

int nSendLen = zmq_send(requester, "M", 1, 0);

char buffer[1000];
int nRecvLen = zmq_recv(requester, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, ZMQ_DONTWAIT);

if( nRecvLen < 0 )
    printf("errno = %d\n", errno);
```

Why would the output be `0` instead of `EAGAIN` (defined as 11 on my system).

EDIT: This is running ZeroMQ version 4.1

Comment: Are you sure about your target API versions? While `ØMQ/3.2.6` uses **`ZMQ_DONTWAIT`** a bit older, sometimes for the sake of distributed versions cross-compatibility still used `ØMQ/2.1.11` API uses **`ZMQ_NOBLOCK`** and returns **`0`** on success, `-1` on failure.

Comment: @user3666197 I'm running version 4.1 of ZeroMQ I think.  Sometimes I grab the wrong document though when looking something up.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, you're saying that `zmq_recv()` is returning -1, your check of `nRecvLen` is passing you to your `printf()`, and your `printf()` is saying `errno = 0`, is that correct?

Comment: @Jason - yes that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is hiding in your `windows` tag (thanks for including *that*).  Relevant: http://api.zeromq.org/4-1:zmq-errno

Specifically:

> The zmq_errno() function is provided to assist users on non-POSIX systems who are experiencing issues with retrieving the correct value of errno directly. Specifically, users on Win32 systems whose application is using a different C run-time library from the C run-time library in use by ØMQ will need to use zmq_errno() for correct operation.

You should be using `zmq_errno()` as opposed to accessing `errno` directly.

Comment: Thanks, I'd been having this problem (in the past) with other API calls as well.